# Retrieve iframe tag having width and height '0' using nokogiri in ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nokogiri, ruby-1.9.2

I want to retrieve the `iframe` tags from `html` code, whose width and height values are 0(zero)
using `nokogiri gem` in `Ruby 1.9.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single xpath statement will do the trick:

```
doc.xpath('//iframe[@width="0" and @height="0"]')
```

This assumes that everything is present in the retrieved HTML. If the `iframe`, `width`, or `height` are only present in the DOM after javascript execution, this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the nokogiri doc should be enough, but : assuming your html doc is stored in `raw_document`, you can do `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(raw_document)`. Then you can use `doc.css('iframe')` to get the list of all iframe tags, and iterate over it to select only the ones you want. Something like `doc.css('iframe[width=0], iframe[height=0]')` might do it directly, but I can't assure it.